# Java Programs Slowing Down After Some Time

Tags: java, performance

I'm working with a java app that does simulations but after about 30 minutes the amount of simulations it can do per second halves.

The simulations are just numerical. The results are buffering, I'm using the Apache POI library to write to excel files, the output should be around 500k rows of 15 columns in excel, it gets written after all simulations are done.

The PC I'm running it on is fast and has good cooling so I don't think it's thermal throttling.

What could be the cause of the slowdown? (I'm not sure what info is important, if you need to know something just ask)

- Temp: 35-45 deg
- CPU Utilization: 70-75%
- Memory Utilization: 6400MB/16333MB

Comment: Have you looked at CPU and memory usage? Do they increase or are constant?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak CPU is hovering around 70% pretty constantly, memory is stable at 6400mb

Comment: It sounds like a memory leak.  The 6400 you list, is it the -Xmx value of your JVM?

Comment: What kind of simulations? Are you sure that the simulations are not just getting more complex?

Comment: @JohnAment There is no -Xmx value in the simulator

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak The simulations don't get more complex over time, it's just a high number of repetitions

Comment: @Crizly So you are executing exactly same code in the loop and at some point - after X iterations - a single iteration takes more time than it did before?

Comment: Have you tried getting runtime info with [Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) and [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html)?

Comment: Ok, I see some more information added. 1. How are you collecting data? E.g. adding new item at the beginning of the ArrayList will be slower the more items there are. Check whether you don't have something like this. 2. Run it with profiler and check what takes the most time.

Comment: Do you use any limited resources that might get exhausted due to improper programming?

Comment: I will take a look at the array thing and have a go with a profiler

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description of the situation, I would claim the JVM is suffering from limited resources (most likely memory) and is being bogged down by increasingly longer and increasingly more frequent GC pauses. You can verify whether or not my gut feeling is correct via logging the GC pauses by specifying the following startup parameters for the JVM:

-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:

Now, if the guess was correct, you can proceed by understanding what is actually causing these long pauses, is it a memory leak or just some unnecessarily big data structure in heap. For this I can recommend to take a [Java monitoring tool called Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu) out for a test drive to see the content inside the memory. Based on the exposed data you can see what to trim down inside memory.

Full disclosure, I am affiliated with Plumbr.